# Using UIMA to extract data from PDF

Tags: pdf, uima

I have a bunch of PDFs which are financial reports of companies. These financial reports are in table form but have different size, shape and format. I want to extract information like current assets, liability and equity and persist them in database.

Can UIMA allow me to do that?

My plan is to use Tika to turn PDF into text, then use UIMA to annotate these text and index these annotation like Current Asset, Current Liability.

Thank you for your hand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a very good usecase for UIMA. A few pointers:

- DKPro Core already has a [PDF reader](https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/source/browse/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core-asl/trunk/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.pdf/pom.xml?r=3) that uses [PDFbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org)
- In case PDFbox does not fit your requirements, I found [PdfTextStream](http://snowtide.com/help/extracting-text-from-pdf-documents) gave good results
- You should have a look at the [RUTA workbench](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.workbench) to write rules to extract information. It will **really** speed up and ease your work with UIMA.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I am studying UIMA RUTA. But I really have difficulties in understanding that. Would you please suggest other resources or tutorials about RUTA besides the ones provided in UIMA website?